# Angular2 - Access component properties from method of properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader, typescript2.0

I'm trying to read a file and store the read content in a private variable of Component. So far, I cannot access properties of components, as I get referral for `this` as `FileReader` not component.

My code is like this

```
private ReadTheFile(file:File) {

    var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    myReader.readAsText(file);
    myReader.onloadend = function (e) {

        //Do something here with myReader.result

    }

    //Get the modified result here, and assign it to public property.

}
```

So, how to access Component properties inside a method like this? Which is method of `FileReader` instance, not Component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the keyword `function` inside a class. This will change the `this` context as you've noticed. use the arrow function

```
private ReadTheFile(file:File) {

    var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    myReader.readAsText(file);
    myReader.onloadend = (e) => {

        //Do something here with myReader.result

    }

    //Get the modified result here, and assign it to public property.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve component context:

```
myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
        //Do something here with myReader.result

    }
```